# Box Plot for Proportion of Logistic Regression Model

Tags: r, plot

I have fit a Logistic Regression model to my data. The estimates for the coefficients and their std.dev are need to be transformed to the probability space using the logit function. I want to make box plots for the upper and lower bounds of 2 standard deviations away from the estimate. I can transform the data easily enough myself with the logit function, but how can I make a box plot in the proportion space?

```
model<-glm(formula = label ~ val, family = binomial(link = "logit"), data=data)
summary(model)

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error  z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -1.3746    0.02972 -167.140  < 2e-16 ***
valTRUE     +0.772    0.05410   -4.394 1.11e-05 ***
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ggcoefstats** from the ggstatplot library has the desired functionality specified with the exponentiate parameter:

```
ggstatsplot::ggcoefstats(
    x = tidy_model,
    statistic = 'z',
    exponentiate = true,
    title=title,
    xlab=xlab,
    ylab=ylab
  )
```

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggstatsplot/ggstatsplot.pdf